# loading a page inside a page or passing js variable to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a php page that also has another php page inside it, this php page has a paginator, is it possible that every time i paginate it would only load the inside page not the whole page?

i tried to go around this by using AJAX as you can see to my first post but i encountered this problem where i need to fetch the letter and page that i sent to ajax and use it again for the pagination, so it would be like javascript sending its variable to php i tried this:

```
 <script>
    function pagereturn()
    {
        return getpage;
    }
 </script>
 <?php  
     $pageno = pagereturn();
     echo $pageno;
  ?>

    function passPaginationAndLetter(page)
    {
    if (page=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
                    document.getElementById("retail_group").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    getpage = page;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","otherpage.php? letter="+getletter+"&pageno="+page,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }

    var page = 1;
    $("#nextButton").click(function(){
        page = page+1;
        passPaginationAndLetter(page);
    });
```

but unfortunately i ended up with no result and broke my code. btw getpage is a variable i took from another function.

Thank you very much, i am still new at javascript thus i am asking you for help. :)

---pagination code at child.php----
    {

```
}
else
{
if ($pageno == 1) {
//echo " FIRST PREV ";
}
else
{
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=1'>FIRST</a> ";
$prevpage = $pageno-1;
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=$prevpage'>PREV</a> ";
}   
echo " ( Page $pageno of $lastpage ) ";
if ($pageno == $lastpage)
{
//echo " NEXT LAST ";
}
else
{
$nextpage = $pageno+1;
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=$nextpage'>NEXT</a> ";
echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pageno=$lastpage'>LAST</a> ";
}
```

---pagination code at parent.php-----

```
else
{
    echo '<a href = "#" onclick="passPaginationAndLetter("1"); return false;">FIRST</a>';
    $prevpage = $pageno-1;
    echo '<a href = "#" onclick="passPaginationAndLetter('.$prevpage.'); return false;">PREV</a>';
}   
echo " ( Page $pageno of $lastpage ) ";
if ($pageno == $lastpage)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $nextpage = $pageno+1;                      
        echo '<a id = "nextButton" href = "#" onclick="passPaginationAndLetter('.$nextpage.'); return false;">NEXT</a>';
        echo '<a href = "#" onclick="passPaginationAndLetter('.$lastpage.'); return false;">LAST</a>';                                              
    }
```

Comment: It had to be said: Pageception.

Comment: it is indeed pageception

Comment: why don't you use jQuery or something for the ajax? it is way much easier and cross platform

Comment: but can jquery can get a php value and pass it to the other page without reloading its parent page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, try this:

Let's say you have your main page, the one who shows all the pagination, called **main.php**, also you have an other php file with all the functions called **functions.php**.

I assume that you have a php function **in functions.php** that genrates a single page of your pagination (`getAJAXpage($page)` for example). This function generates a complete HTML page, something like this (REMEMBER this is just an example, could be implemented by 1000 different ways):

```
<?php //functions.php file
...
public function getAJAXpage($page){
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];//im not pretty sure about this :S
    $elements = getElements($page);//this function returns the set of elements in your page
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($elements as $e){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$e.'</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
...
?>
```

what you can do in your php page **main.php** (the one who shows all the pagination) something like this:

```
function getAjaxPage(page){ //this is a javascript code in main.php file   
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'html',
        url:'the-url-for-your-getAJAXpage-function',
        success:function(data){
            $("#your-pagination-element").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I also assume that in your pagination page's html in your **main.php** file you have at least a set of buttons (or icons) to direct the pagination (next, prev, first, last,...). So you can add this code to the above javascript.

```
//more javascript in main.php
var page = 1;
$("#nextButton").click(function(){
    page = page+1;
    getAjaxPage(page);
});
```

and so with all the buttons.

**NOTE:** in this answer I also assume that you use the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) libray, highly recomended for begginers in javascript.

Hope I helped you. Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain it to more briefly, im a little bit confused on what is getajaxpage for and where it is placed also for the nextbutton.click, im really new with javascript, hope you understand. thank you. :) btw i am using jquery but for pagination its pure php thus i wished to pass the variable to php, but if there is a better way do let me know. thanks.

Comment: i understand it now, in my case i have parent.php that calls the child.php that holds the pagination process which does not use jquery it is purely php. now i also have a set of pagination in parent.php that uses ajax to change the pages at child.php since i only wish for the child to load not the whole page. but i cant get it to keep the number it passed to the child to be used as a reference for the parent.php pagination. now i made a loop to view all the number of pages available. unfortunately my problem now is the letter since it is a letter grouping function. i will post the code